# How to split string in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, split

I have a menu with PNG icons. I want when user hover menu item, PNG icon change to GIF icon. i tried this:
 [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/KK8FQ/)

```
$("#image").mouseenter(function(){
    // I can set GIF url here
    $(this).attr("src","http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png");
});

$("#image").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).attr("src","http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo-white.png");
});
```

but I know this is not right way. I can not do this for every menu item.
this is my HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a> item 1
        <img src="image-path" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a> item 2
        <img src="image-path" />
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16711504/how-to-split-the-string-using-jquery-or-javascript) but this is not what I want. I want to split on last `.` or last `/` in path.

this code split string on every `/` character:

```
var data =$("#image").attr("src");
var array = data.split('/');
```

**Question:**

I have this image path: `../images/icon1.png` and I want to change it to these paths:

`../images/icon1.gif` or `../images/hover/icon1.gif`

Comment: Do this with CSS and sprites preferably. JS is overkill and actually provides a worse user experience (image flicker as the secondary one loads)

Comment: I have many menu item and special icon for each one.

Comment: Or you could use a simple javascript `replace`.

Comment: Even if I had 10,000 menu items all with images and icons, I would still use CSS. You're slowing down the performance if you're adding so many event handlers as well. Use a script to generate the required CSS if you find it's too much manual work.

Comment: @ericosg: I don't know the path and new path. what I know is that `.png` and `gif` file is in same place

Comment: so then `$(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace('.png', '.gif'));`

Comment: @Mohsen do you want the image path to change on hover of `li` or `image`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$('ul img').hover(function (e) {
    $(this).attr('src', function (idx, src) {
        return src.replace(/(.)(png|gif)$/i, '.' + (e.type == 'mouseenter' ? 'gif': 'png'))
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hDgSj/)

Comment: this is exactly what i want

Comment: thanks Arun, your code is working but I don't understand it, can you introduce some resource ?

Answer (score 3):

There is no need of js for this.

it can be done simply using css.

```
image{background-image:url(../images/icon.png);}
image:hover{background-image:url(../images/icon1.png);}
```

Comment: I have many item menu and special icon for each one. your code work if I have one icon for all menu item.

Comment: You can use `sprite`. Read more information here http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp

Comment: @Hiral that's a terrible resource. Is the same documented anywhere else, say, MDN?

Comment: first: this is not background!!!! and second: I have many Item!!! look at this  http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/KK8FQ/1/

Comment: I want to change image src path not image background path

Comment: @JanDvorak The [css-tricks post](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) linked in my answer is quite good...

Comment: @Hiral: this is trouble solution. it is easier with JQuery, think about that if you have +30 item!

Comment: it might look difficult in coding but just think **only 1 image file(i.e. sprite)** is loaded on your page. on the other hand, if you achieve this using js, every time user hovers and hovers out the image, new image is loaded on the page. the **amount of resources will be 30*2** in case of 30 items. 

and yes, you should not go for sprite if your image file exceeds around 200KB.

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050152/why-use-a-sprite-sheet-rather-than-individual-images for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Just trim off the last three characters:

```
var oldSrc = this.src;
this.src = oldSrc.substr(0,oldSrc.length-3)+"png";
// or +"gif" to change to the GIF image.
```

Answer (score 1):

Did this do the trick ?

```
$(this).attr('src', 'http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo-white.png');
```

Comment: This is the same as his question, just with single quotes? I think you've missed the point :P

Answer (score 1):

Hiral is correct, you do not need JS for this.

Try the following:

```
.icon {
    width: 32px; /* Replace with your own */
    height: 32px; /* Replace with your own */
}
.icon-house {
    background-image:url(../images/icon-house.png);
}
.icon-house:hover {
    background-image:url(../images/icon-house-hover.png);
}
.icon-car {
    background-image:url(../images/icon-car.png);
}
.icon-car:hover {
    background-image:url(../images/icon-car-hover.png);
}
/* etc... */
```

And change your HTML to something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="index.html">Home
        <span class="icon icon-house"></span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="carsrock.html">Cars are awesome!
        <span class="icon icon-car"></span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Alternatively, you can use a spritesheet, which would save time for your users as well, as they would not need to download many separate small images.

This article is relevant: http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Comment: I want to change image path not span background path

Comment: @Mohsen The `span`s will have background images, which will be your icons, and will look exactly the same. Or is it not possible for you to change the HTML?

Comment: this is trouble solution. it is easier with JQuery, think about that if you have +30 item! then you need to create +60 class, also I don't know the background path.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression to replace the path:

```
var newSrc = $(this).attr("src").replace(/\.png$/, ".gif");
$(this).attr("src", newSrc);
```